# I have to show and hide column of a table on basis of value of flag stored in second table

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework

[First table contains flag(1 for show 0 for hide) for column that were present in second table. I have to show Columns of second table based on the flag stored in first table.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aISs.png)

First Table:

```
Id  columnName    isHidden  
1   Name           1           
2   Email          1           
3   Password       0           
4   Country        1           
5   State          1           
6   filename       1           
7   Salary         1
```

Second Table:

```
Name    Password    Country   State     filename        Salary   Email
tom     tom           India  Haryana    6f0fbcec.jpg    9100.00  tom@mail.com
Mark    test          India  Haryana    b7f14d8a.png    8800.00  te@gmail.com
fdgd    gffdg         India   Delhi      d12f0438.txt   9100.00  abs@mail.com
```

Comment: Please include your table data directly in the question as _text_.

Comment: which field to use, firstpage or secondpage?

Comment: So, what are you expected results here. SQL Server doesn't display data in "pages"; it returns datasets.

Comment: i have to show columns of second table on basis of flag (1 for show 0 for hide) stored in first table

Comment: With SQL, the only way you could do it would be with Dynamic SQL. What is your presentation layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to declare each column separately, like George has, you could build it using `FOR XML PATH`:

```
USE Sandbox;
GO

CREATE TABLE FirstTable (Id int, columnName sysname, isHidden bit);

INSERT INTO FirstTable
VALUES (1,N'Name',1),
       (2,N'Email',1),
       (3,N'Password',0),
       (4,N'Country',1),
       (5,N'State',1),
       (6,N'filename',1),
       (7,N'Salary',1);
GO

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

SET @SQL = N'SELECT ' + ISNULL(STUFF((SELECT N',' + NCHAR(10) + N'       ' + QUOTENAME(columnName)
                                  FROM FirstTable
                                  WHERE isHidden = 1 --0 (false) for the column "isHidden"? Seem counter intuitive. 
                                  FOR XML PATH(N'')),1,9,N''),N'*') + NCHAR(10) +
           N'FROM SecondTable;';
PRINT @SQL; --Your Best Friend
--EXEC sp_executesql @SQL; --Uncomment to execute
GO
DROP TABLE FirstTable;
```

If, however, you're using SSRS, I would actually rather use an expression there that hides the columns, rather than building dynamic SQL like that. Especially as SSRS can't handle dynamic columns.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use dynamic SQL:

```
declare @sqlcmd nvarchar(max)=
    'select '
    +STUFF( -- stuff is used to remove the first comma
     case when (select isHidden from your_first_table where Id=1)=0 then ',Name'        else '' end
    +case when (select isHidden from your_first_table where Id=2)=0 then ',Email'       else '' end
    +case when (select isHidden from your_first_table where Id=3)=0 then ',Password'    else '' end
    +case when (select isHidden from your_first_table where Id=4)=0 then ',Country'     else '' end
    +case when (select isHidden from your_first_table where Id=5)=0 then ',State'       else '' end
    +case when (select isHidden from your_first_table where Id=6)=0 then ',filename'    else '' end
    +case when (select isHidden from your_first_table where Id=7)=0 then ',Salary'      else '' end
    ,1,1,'')
    +' from your_second_table'

exec (@sqlcmd)
```

Note that this will throw an error if all columns have isHidden=1

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help

```
DECLARE @SQLStatement NVARCHAR(MAX) = N''

DECLARE  @Columns_to_show NVARCHAR(MAX) = N''

SELECT @Columns_to_show = @Columns_to_show + ', QUOTENAME(columnName) 
FROM
    (SELECT columnName FROM [INPUT_TABLE1] WHERE isHidden = 0) DT

SET @SQLStatement = N'SELECT' +  @Columns_to_show + 'FROM [INPUT_TABLE2]'
```

Comment: I would suggest `QUOTENAME` over `[' +columnName+ ']'`.